# Creating vanity nameservers without hosting DNS

Tags: nameserver, dns-hosting, a-record, dns-server

We'd like to create our own vanity nameserver addresses to use with various domains that we host.

Our hosting provider gives us two options: use their nameserver addresses, or setup our own nameserver addresses and host our own DNS.

We don't want to host our own DNS, we just want to mask our provider's nameserver addresses with our own.

Let's say our provider's nameserver addresses are ns1.provider.com and ns2.provider.com and our domain is example.com

My intention is to obtain the IP addresses for ns1.provider.com and ns2.provider.com and then setup A-records for ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com using those two IP addresses.

We'd then setup glue records with our domain registrar using the same two IP addresses.

Would this work? Is there any reason NOT to do this? The only reason I can think of is if our provider changes the IP addresses of their nameservers without telling us, then our DNS lookups would break.

Comment: Consider something designed specifically for this, like http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html

Answer (score 0):

The [reverse resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) of your vanity nameserver would not work, because it depends on the name server's real IP; it is of the form

```
1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.     IN       PTR       ns1.provider.com.
```

So when clients attempt to verify the identity of your vanity nameserver ns1.example.com, via the in-addr.arpa reverse resolution domain, an inconsistency would be revealed and depending on how strictly they adhere to security protocols, they might disregard any answers from those servers.

Why not host your own DNS ?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone checking this in an automated manner.